# UV mapping not filling faces

Tags: uv

I have tried to map this simple object, but the uv mapping does not correspond to what i see in the textured object. It cuts the image a bit on top and a bit on the bottom of the faces. It does not fill the faces with the texture, even though i have mapped them correctly. Does anyone know what could be happening?
Thanks in advance.[image: Uvmapping]

Comment: Do you have a subserf modifier and multiple materials assigned to your object? If not, could you upload your .blend? It's hard to say what is causing this without testing each possible cause separately.

Comment: Maybe Gandalf3 is onto something there with the sub-D thing.  An error similar to that will happen for uneven geometry if the 2 sub-division modifiers are not set correctly.  Try toggling the Subdivide UV's option on and off.  Stretching can occur if the geometry is not evenly spaced.  From the look of your mesh I'd say that you should have this option activated.  If that is the problem you can also add control loops to create evenly spaced division vertically.

Comment: Thank you  MarcClintDion and gandalf3 . My geometry was uneven and i was using the sub-division modifier and multiple materials to the object. I added control loops and created evenly spaced divisions as you suggested and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

This can be caused by a combination of subsurf and multiple materials.

You'll notice that when you assign the materials to a model with subsurf, in some cases they don't line up with the edit cage. In these cases, if you either apply the subsurf modifier to the edit cage or disable it completely, the materials line up with the topology:

[image]

To fix this distortion caused by the subsurf, add supporting geometry or creases.

- For adding supporting geometry, the loop cut (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) and bevel (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>) tools work pretty well.
- You can change the crease weight of selected edges by pressing  <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>.

[image]