# Mapping of texture changes when using subsurf modifier

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor, subdivision-surface

I'm a beginnner with Blender and I try to train myself watching videos tuts, but today I'm confronted with a small problem that I can't find the answer.

As the pictures describe better than the words, I made a small picture describing my problem.

My problem is that I can't get a UV Map with the right size and the correct deformation. I tried several things but I can't do it. Could you please help me to fix my problem and especially to understand how to do it.

[image]

Comment: You need more geometry or set some crease weight. see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8452/uv-mapping-not-filling-faces