# problem in assigning material

Tags: mesh, materials

i should start with that i am quite new to 3D and blender.

here is my problem:

while in edit mode i select the faces and assign a new material to those faces but material doesnt cover the whole face. i can see 2 horizontal lines on the vireframe which material is assigned between those 2 lines instead of whole face i can select . i cant select or edit those 2 horizontal lines. any help would be much appreciated. thanx in advance. .[image: here is the screenshot of selected faces and applied material]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Comment: unfortunatelly no, it doesnt help, as you can see in the screenshots its not applying to whole faces i select thats the problem.

Comment: the Subdivision Surface modifier will virtually change the position of your edge loops, you can verify if you enable the modifier's On Cage option, therefore it will change how the material is displayed. You need to add edge loops if you want your material to stick to the position

Comment: I'd suggest unwrap the geometry properly an create a black and white mask, see the second answer of the linked Q&A.

Comment: "the Subdivision Surface modifier will virtually change the position of your edge loops, you can verify if you enable the modifier's On Cage option, therefore it will change how the material is displayed. You need to add edge loops if you want your material to stick to the position" yesssss!!!

Comment: thank you very  much moonboots, :D

Comment: you're welcome  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Subdivision Surface* modifier will virtually change the position of your edge loops, you can verify if you enable the modifier's *On Cage* option, therefore it will change how the material is displayed. You need to add edge loops if you want your material to stick to the position you want.

That said, as pointed out by Brockmann, maybe consider the other solution that would be to unwrap your object and create a b&w mask that would separate the glass from the label texture.

Comment: you are the man :D thank you very much.

Comment: *Or/and* up the crease weights: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/16403/31447 A hack anyway...

Comment: sure, I'm personally not fan of crease though

Comment: I'm not a fan of adding extra loops :D

Comment: you make me sad  :'(  I love edge loops, creases are just fake

Comment: Wasn't my point, I wouldn't add any extra loops to texture something... messy IMHO

Comment: you're right but in that case creases are not clean either, as you say creating a b&w mask is probably the best (but I was just answering to the why)